# Package Versions of ROS-Noetic

Tags: ros, apt, raspberrypi, rosversion, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[The ROS-wiki explained that a ROS distribution is a versioned set of ROS packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) but where can i find a list of the packages that were used and their version for the Noetic distribution?

I installed ROS on a Raspberry Pi4 / Raspberry-OS with sudo apt-get install ros-base-dev and I need to know which distribution this would be closest to.

When i start the roscore i get the following output (would upload a screenshot but i dont have enough points yet):

```
...
ros_comm version 1.14.3
...
PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: Debian
* /rosversion: 1.14.3
...
```

I am very grateful for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373225/package-versions-of-ros-noetic/) by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-03**:\

> would upload a screenshot but i dont have enough points yet

From [wiki/Support](https://wiki.ros.org/Support):

> Please **DO NOT** post a screenshot of the terminal or source file [..]

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-03**:
Please note:

> ```
> /rosdistro: Debian
> ```

this suggests you've actually installed the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) instead of a regular ROS install.

Please read the linked page and be aware of the differences and difficulties you can encounter with that.

**Comment by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on 2021-03-03**:
Please DO NOT post a screenshot of the terminal or source file [..]

I am sorry i will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ignoring the fact you've likely not installed ROS Noetic, but an upstream version:

> where can i find a list of the packages that were used and their version for the Noetic distribution?

one way to see which versions of packages are currently part of the released set would be to visit the [Noetic status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html), which lists the versions of all packages in the *Version* column.

This information is only accurate for versions of ROS installed from `repositories.ros.org`, not for the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

Note that the page linked is for the `amd64` build. For RPi you'll have to look at the pages for `arm64` or `arm32` for Debian or Ubuntu at [repositories.ros.org/status_page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page).

And also note: *only* those OS versions get binary packages built by the ROS buildfarm. On other OS (such as the popular Raspbian) you'll have to build from source.

---

Edit: another option would be to look at the [noetic/distribution.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/7ff6b1a77cc0e171b86d8b51974ccc3f760cce3d/noetic/distribution.yaml) file. This contains all packages released with Bloom. Part of the metadata is the version of the released package.

For `ros_comm` for instance:

```
  ros_comm:
    [..]
    release:
      packages:
      [..]
      - ros_comm
      [..]
      tags:
        release: release/noetic/{package}/{version}
      url: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git
      version: 1.15.9-1
    source:
      [..]
    status: maintained
```

which also shows that your version of `ros_comm` is rather old.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on 2021-03-03**:
I am very grateful for you answer. Thank you very much gvdhoorn! I think the upstream version is not the right solution for my use-case then because it is older and [has some differences in comparison to the original ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). I didn't know that. I will try to build it from source because i must use raspberry os.